# ¿Cómo se puede eliminar un elemento desde de un Fragment en la base de Datos en RealTime Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Esta parte lee los datos y los muestra en el recyclerview, cuando se presiona un imageview dentro de cada item del array, si detecta el id y el objeto pero no lo borra en la base de datos, ya hasta se puso las reglas todas en true, pero ni así lo logro

```
ref=database.getReference("Productos");
 ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()){
                Offer e=snapshot1.getValue(Offer.class);
                mList.add(e);
            }
            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OfferAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void deleteItem(int position) {
                    String id=mList.get(position).getId();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Productos").child(id).child("token").removeValue();
                }
            });
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

Este es la parte del adapter donde se hace click sobre la imagen en cuestión

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void deleteItem(int position);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    mlistener=listener;
}
    public OfferViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        //Recuperamos de la vista las variables
  
        btndelete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btndelete);

        btndelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener!=null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        listener.deleteItem(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Aquí está la estructura de la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: nos podrias mostrar la estructura de tu base de datos ?

Comment: Ya está la estructura de la base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cuando haces getValue , el id no es puesto automaticamente en tu objeto offer, podes chequearlo poniendo un punto de debug.

Lo que deberias hacer es construirlo a mano y usar getKey() para obtener el id de cada objeto cuando iteras

```
for(DataSnapshot snapshot1:snapshot.getChildren()){
                Offer offer = new Offer();
                String offerId = snapshot1.getkey();
                //tus otras variables
                offer.setId(offerId);
                mList.add(offer);
            }
```

Comment: Me ha servido, muchas gracias